# What does a class diagram do?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

I'm taking up system analysis and design currently but my school does not offer object oriented design to me. I'm very lost as to what a class diagram do. I've tried searching online for help but their explanation is slightly too difficult for me to understand.

For example, I have 2 actors : Students and Principal. The students are able to view the statistics of past electives(how many students took the elective) while the principal can maintain the statistics system. On top of that, he can view the feedbacks from other students regarding the system

How do I construct a case diagram with this scenario?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `use case` or `class` diagram you need?

Comment: @Fabio a class diagram..

Comment: he probably meant CASE as "Computer-aided software engineering".

Answer (score 0):

Underline/Bold all the nouns in your descrption.

For example, I have 2 **actors** : **Students** and **Principal**. The students are able to *view* the **statistics** of past **electives**(how many students took the elective) while the principal can *maintain* the statistics system. On top of that, he can *view* the **feedbacks** from other students regarding the **system**

I would say the important entities are **student**, **principle**, **elective**, **feedback** and **system**. Draw a square for each of these entities on a piece of paper and start thinking about what kind of lines can be used to join the  boxes.

What relationships can you see?

Lets look at **feedback**. A pincipal can *view* many feedbacks, and a student can *write* many feedbacks. Draw a one-to-many line from pincipal to feedback, and a one-to-many line from student to feedback.

The system is composed of these feedback entries, so you could use a *composition* *line* to indicate the system is composed of feedback enties.

That should be enough to give you a start.